# NullPointerException and "Depth limit reached" sending SOAP after first try

Tags: java, soap, ibm-was

I'm getting an error on sending SOAP message to a Web Service server, the funny thing is the first sending (once the server gets started) always works.
From the second message on I start receiving a NullPointerException at client end and "depth limit reached" messages at server.
That made me believe I was facing a server memory problem. Thus I enabled Verbose Garbage Collection and doubled the Max Heap Size on Server but the problem did not disappear.
I'm using Java 6 and WebSphere Application Server v7.
Your help is welcome,
thank you

### ## Error log on client ##

```
    AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: java.lang.NullPointerException
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
    at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at mc_style.functions.soap.sap.document.sap_com.ICT_SERVICE_DESK_APISoapBindingStub.addInfo(ICT_SERVICE_DESK_APISoapBindingStub.java:921)
    at com.ibm.de.css.SolClientWork.SendAddInfoToSAP(SolClientWork.java:1762)
    at com.ibm.de.css.SolClientWork.run(SolClientWork.java:202)

    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:leoferri
```

### ## Event log file on Server ##

```
[4/17/14 16:25:20:576 BRT]     FFDC Exception:org.apache.axis2.AxisFault SourceId:com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet.doPost ProbeId:516 Reporter:com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet@402c402c
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.dispatcher.JavaBeanDispatcher.createFaultResponse(JavaBeanDispatcher.java:357)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.dispatcher.JavaBeanDispatcher.invoke(JavaBeanDispatcher.java:111)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.EndpointController.invoke(EndpointController.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.JAXWSMessageReceiver.receive(JAXWSMessageReceiver.java:159)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:188)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:275)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet.doPost(WASAxis2Servlet.java:1351)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1655)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:937)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:500)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:864)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:272)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1550)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.dispatcher.JavaDispatcher.invokeTargetOperation(JavaDispatcher.java:82)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.dispatcher.JavaBeanDispatcher.invoke(JavaBeanDispatcher.java:98)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sap.document.sap.soap.functions.mc_style.ICT_SERVICE_DESK_APISoapBindingImpl.addInfo(ICT_SERVICE_DESK_APISoapBindingImpl.java:140)
    ... 34 more

Reporter BEGIN:com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet@402c402c
javax.servlet.GenericServlet::LSTRING_FILE:javax.servlet.LocalStrings
javax.servlet.GenericServlet::lStrings BEGIN:java.util.PropertyResourceBundle@1a6a1a6a
 java.util.PropertyResourceBundle@1a6a1a6a
 END:java.util.PropertyResourceBundle@1a6a1a6a

javax.servlet.GenericServlet::config:null
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet::METHOD_DELETE:DELETE
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet::METHOD_HEAD:HEAD
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet::METHOD_GET:GET
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet::METHOD_OPTIONS:OPTIONS
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet::METHOD_POST:POST
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet::METHOD_PUT:PUT
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet::METHOD_TRACE:TRACE
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet::HEADER_IFMODSINCE:If-Modified-Since
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet::HEADER_LASTMOD:Last-Modified
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet::LSTRING_FILE:javax.servlet.http.LocalStrings
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet::lStrings BEGIN:java.util.PropertyResourceBundle@731d731d
 java.util.PropertyResourceBundle@731d731d
 END:java.util.PropertyResourceBundle@731d731d

javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet::class$javax$servlet$http$HttpServlet:null
org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet::log BEGIN:org.apache.axis2.util.OnDemandLogger@60056005
 org.apache.axis2.util.OnDemandLogger::c:class org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet
 org.apache.axis2.util.OnDemandLogger::_log:null
 END:org.apache.axis2.util.OnDemandLogger@60056005

org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet::CONFIGURATION_CONTEXT:CONFIGURATION_CONTEXT
org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet::SESSION_ID:SessionId
org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet::configContext BEGIN:org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContext@4ed44ed4
 org.apache.axis2.context.AbstractContext::log BEGIN:org.apache.axis2.util.OnDemandLogger@42d942d9
  org.apache.axis2.util.OnDemandLogger::c:class org.apache.axis2.context.AbstractContext
   org.apache.axis2.util.OnDemandLogger::_log:org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger@19e219e2 depth limit reached
  END:org.apache.axis2.util.OnDemandLogger@42d942d9

 org.apache.axis2.context.AbstractContext::DEFAULT_MAP_SIZE:64
 org.apache.axis2.context.AbstractContext::DEBUG_ENABLED:false
 org.apache.axis2.context.AbstractContext::DEBUG_PROPERTY_SET:false
 org.apache.axis2.context.AbstractContext::isClusteringOn:false
 org.apache.axis2.context.AbstractContext::isClusteringCheckDone:true
 org.apache.axis2.context.AbstractContext::COPY_PROPERTIES:CopyProperties
 org.apache.axis2.context.AbstractContext::lastTouchedTime:1397762720573
 org.apache.axis2.context.AbstractContext::parent:null
 org.apache.axis2.context.AbstractContext::properties BEGIN:java.util.HashMap@4e6e4e6e
  {
  key:com.ibm.ws.websvcs.JAXWS_CATALOG_ACCESSOR
   value:com.ibm.ws.websvcs.wsdl.JaxWSCatalogAccessor@4e9a4e9a depth limit reached
  key:fragileIdentityReferenceParameter
   value:org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl@a120a12 depth limit reached
  key:com.ibm.ws.websvcs.CONFIG_CONTEXT_ROOT
  value:SapSolManWebservice
  key:com.ibm.ws.websvcs.URL_SERVICES_MAPPINGS
   value:java.util.HashMap@7bf87bf8 depth limit reached
  key:com.ibm.ws.websvcs.FILE_PATH_SERVLET_MAPPINGS
   value:java.util.HashMap@4e3c4e3c depth limit reached
  key:intermediaryPresentReferenceParameter
   value:org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl@a5f0a5f depth limit reached
  key:org.apache.axis2.jaxws.addressing.util.EndpointContextMap
   value:org.apache.axis2.jaxws.addressing.util.EndpointContextMap@48694869 depth limit reached
  key:com.ibm.ws.websvcs.ENDPOINT_MANAGER_MBEAN
   value:com.ibm.ws.webservices.management.EndpointManagerMBeanImpl@79557955 depth limit reached
  key:virtualHostNameReferenceParameter
   value:org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl@a330a33 depth limit reached
  }
  END:java.util.HashMap@4e6e4e6e

 org.apache.axis2.context.AbstractContext::propertyDifferences:null
 org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContext::log BEGIN:org.apache.axis2.util.OnDemandLogger@4ed14ed1
  org.apache.axis2.util.OnDemandLogger::c:class org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContext
   org.apache.axis2.util.OnDemandLogger::_log:org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger@119c119c depth limit reached
  END:org.apache.axis2.util.OnDemandLogger@4ed14ed1

 org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContext::operationContextMap BEGIN:java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap@4ee04ee0
  {
  }
  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap::serialVersionUID:7249069246763182397
  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap::DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY:16
  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap::DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR:0.75
  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap::DEFAULT_CONCURRENCY_LEVEL:16
  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap::MAXIMUM_CAPACITY:1073741824
  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap::MAX_SEGMENTS:65536
  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap::RETRIES_BEFORE_LOCK:2
  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap::segmentMask:15
  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap::segmentShift:28
   java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap::segments:[Ljava.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Segment;@4ee64ee6 depth limit reached
  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap::keySet:null
   java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap::entrySet:java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$EntrySet@18a618a6 depth limit reached
  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap::values:null
  END:java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap@4ee04ee0

 org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContext::serviceGroupContextMap BEGIN:java.util.Hashtable@4fbc4fbc
  {
  }
  END:java.util.Hashtable@4fbc4fbc

 org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContext::applicationSessionServiceGroupContexts BEGIN:java.util.Hashtable@4fc94fc9
  {
  }
  END:java.util.Hashtable@4fc94fc9

 org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContext::axisConfiguration BEGIN:org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration@54e054e
  org.apache.axis2.description.AxisDescription::parent:null
   org.apache.axis2.description.AxisDescription::parameterInclude:org.apache.axis2.description.ParameterIncludeImpl@2bd02bd depth limit reached
  org.apache.axis2.description.AxisDescription::policyInclude:null
   org.apache.axis2.description.AxisDescription::policySubject:org.apache.axis2.description.PolicySubject@42c042c depth limit reached
   org.apache.axis2.description.AxisDescription::children:java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap@2e702e7 depth limit reached
   org.apache.axis2.description.AxisDescription::engagedModules:java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap@9a109a1 depth limit reached
  org.apache.axis2.description.AxisDescription::parameterObservers:null
   org.apache.axis2.description.AxisDescription::omFactory:org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.factory.OMLinkedListImplFactory@67d067d0 depth limit reached
  org.apache.axis2.description.AxisDescription::documentation:null
   org.apache.axis2.description.AxisDescription::log:org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger@cc00cc0 depth limit reached
   org.apache.axis2.description.AxisDescription::NULL_MODULES:java.util.ArrayList@9360936 depth limit reached
   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration::log:org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger@6d0a6d0a depth limit reached
   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration::dataLocators:java.util.HashMap@4420442 depth limit reached
   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration::dataLocatorClassNames:java.util.HashMap@4520452 depth limit reached
   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration::allModules:java.util.HashMap@4620462 depth limit reached
   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration::nameToversionMap:java.util.HashMap@4720472 depth limit reached
   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration::transportsIn:java.util.HashMap@4820482 depth limit reached
   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration::transportsOut:java.util.HashMap@4920492 depth limit reached
   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration::policySupportedModules:java.util.HashMap@4a204a2 depth limit reached
   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration::localPolicyAssertions:java.util.ArrayList@96c096c depth limit reached
   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration::observersList:java.util.ArrayList@14941494 depth limit reached
  org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration::axis2Repository:null
   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration::allServices:java.util.HashMap@4c104c1 depth limit reached
   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration::allEndpoints:java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap@4d104d1 depth limit reached
   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration::globalModuleList:java.util.ArrayList@5e205e2 depth limit reached
   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration::faultyModules:java.util.Hashtable@290e290e depth limit reached
   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration::faultyServices:java.util.Hashtable@6920692 depth limit reached
   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration::inFaultPhases:java.util.ArrayList@b4a0b4a depth limit reached
   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration::inPhasesUptoAndIncludingPostDispatch:java.util.ArrayList@408c408c depth limit reached
   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration::messageReceivers:java.util.HashMap@5ed05ed depth limit reached
   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration::messageBuilders:java.util.HashMap@5fd05fd depth limit reached
   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration::messageFormatters:java.util.HashMap@6610661 depth limit reached
   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration::moduleClassLoader:org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader@24bc24bc depth limit reached
   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration::moduleConfigmap:java.util.HashMap@5d205d2 depth limit reached
   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration::outFaultPhases:java.util.ArrayList@40c640c6 depth limit reached
   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration::outPhases:java.util.ArrayList@40974097 depth limit reached
   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration::phasesinfo:org.apache.axis2.deployment.util.PhasesInfo@14ac14ac depth limit reached
  org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration::serviceClassLoader:org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader@24bc24bc
  org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration::systemClassLoader:org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader@24bc24bc
  org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration::start:false
   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration::targetResolvers:java.util.ArrayList@14dc14dc depth limit reached
  org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration::clusterManager:null
  org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration::configurator:null
  END:org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration@54e054e

 org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContext::threadPool:null
 org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContext::listenerManager BEGIN:org.apache.axis2.engine.ListenerManager@5fe45fe4
   org.apache.axis2.engine.ListenerManager::log:org.apache.axis2.util.OnDemandLogger@5fe15fe1 depth limit reached
  org.apache.axis2.engine.ListenerManager::defaultConfigurationContext:org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContext@4ed44ed4
  org.apache.axis2.engine.ListenerManager::configctx:org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContext@4ed44ed4
   org.apache.axis2.engine.ListenerManager::startedTransports:java.util.HashMap@5fe75fe7 depth limit reached
  org.apache.axis2.engine.ListenerManager::stopped:false
  END:org.apache.axis2.engine.ListenerManager@5fe45fe4

 org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContext::serviceGroupContextTimoutInterval:30000
 org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContext::contextRoot:axis2
 org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContext::servicePath:services
 org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContext::cachedServicePath:axis2/services
 org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContext::contextListeners:null
 org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContext::stopped:false
 END:org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContext@4ed44ed4

org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet::axisConfiguration:org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration@54e054e
org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet::servletConfig BEGIN:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletConfigImpl@20772077
 com.ibm.ws.container.BaseConfiguration::_id:com.sap.document.sap.soap.functions.mc_style.ICT_SERVICE_DESK_APISoapBindingImpl
 com.ibm.ws.container.BaseConfiguration::name:null
 com.ibm.ws.container.BaseConfiguration::_attributes:null
 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.TargetConfig::initParams:null
 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.TargetConfig::isJsp:false
 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.TargetConfig::fileName:null
 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.TargetConfig::displayName:Web services servlet
 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.TargetConfig::name:null
 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.TargetConfig::description:null
 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.TargetConfig::smallIcon:null
 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.TargetConfig::largeIcon:null
 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletConfig::servletName:com.sap.document.sap.soap.functions.mc_style.ICT_SERVICE_DESK_APISoapBindingImpl
 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletConfig::className:com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet
 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletConfig::mappings BEGIN:java.util.ArrayList@b940b94
  {
   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletMapping@b9f0b9f depth limit reached
   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletMapping@c800c80 depth limit reached
   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletMapping@d7d0d7d depth limit reached
  }
  END:java.util.ArrayList@b940b94

 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletConfig::startUpWeight:1
 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletConfig::DEFAULT_STARTUP:-1
 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletConfig::isCachingEnabled:true
 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletConfig::isStatisticsEnabled:true
 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletConfig::context BEGIN:com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.facade.ServletContextFacade@292e292e
   com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.facade.ServletContextFacade::context:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl@77ef77ef depth limit reached
  END:com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.facade.ServletContextFacade@292e292e

 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletConfig::isInternal:false
 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletConfig::metaData BEGIN:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebComponentMetaDataImpl@20f120f1
   com.ibm.ws.runtime.metadata.MetaDataImpl::tc:com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent@584c584c depth limit reached
   com.ibm.ws.runtime.metadata.MetaDataImpl::slots:[Ljava.lang.Object;@20fd20fd depth limit reached
  com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebComponentMetaDataImpl::securityMetaData:null
  com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebComponentMetaDataImpl::logger:com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.logging.WebContainerLogger@5e3d5e3d
  com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebComponentMetaDataImpl::CLASS_NAME:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebComponentMetaDataImpl
  com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebComponentMetaDataImpl::_name:com.sap.document.sap.soap.functions.mc_style.ICT_SERVICE_DESK_APISoapBindingImpl
  com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebComponentMetaDataImpl::_implementationClass:com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet
   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebComponentMetaDataImpl::_javaColonContext:javax.naming.InitialContext@1cf61cf6 depth limit reached
   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebComponentMetaDataImpl::_mmd:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebModuleMetaDataImpl@587d587d depth limit reached
   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebComponentMetaDataImpl::_j2eeName:com.ibm.ejs.csi.J2EENameImpl@20832083 depth limit reached
  com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebComponentMetaDataImpl::_webComponentType:1
  com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebComponentMetaDataImpl::_webComponentVersion:2.5
   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebComponentMetaDataImpl::_resRefList:com.ibm.ejs.csi.ResRefListImpl@582d582d depth limit reached
   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebComponentMetaDataImpl::_localTran:com.ibm.ejs.csi.LocalTranConfigDataImpl@65606560 depth limit reached
  com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebComponentMetaDataImpl::_globalTran:null
  com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebComponentMetaDataImpl::_webGlobalTran:null
  com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebComponentMetaDataImpl::_jns:null
  com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebComponentMetaDataImpl::_webComponentDescription:null
  com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebComponentMetaDataImpl::_webComponentInitParameters:null
  com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebComponentMetaDataImpl::_pageList:null
  com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebComponentMetaDataImpl::_state:0
  com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebComponentMetaDataImpl::config:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletConfigImpl@20772077
  com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebComponentMetaDataImpl::VALID:0
  com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebComponentMetaDataImpl::DESTROYED:1
  com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebComponentMetaDataImpl::lock:java.lang.Object@21012101
  com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebComponentMetaDataImpl::invocationCallbacksContext:null
   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebComponentMetaDataImpl::invocationCallbacksStorage:com.ibm.ws.util.WSThreadLocal@af70af7 depth limit reached
  END:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebComponentMetaDataImpl@20f120f1

 END:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletConfigImpl@20772077

org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet::agent:null
org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet::contextRoot:null
org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet::disableREST:false
org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet::LIST_SERVICES_SUFFIX:/services/listServices
org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet::LIST_FAULTY_SERVICES_SUFFIX:/services/ListFaultyServices
org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet::closeReader:true
org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet::BUFFER_SIZE:8192
org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet::initCalled:false
com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet::_tc BEGIN:com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent@60086008
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivLevel:10
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivName:com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivDebugEnabled:false
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivEventEnabled:false
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivEntryEnabled:false
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivDetailEnabled:false
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivConfigEnabled:false
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivInfoEnabled:true
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivServiceEnabled:true
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivWarningEnabled:true
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivErrorEnabled:true
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivFatalEnabled:true
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent::defaultMessageFile:com.ibm.ejs.resources.seriousMessages
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent::EXTENSION_NAME_DPID:DiagnosticProvider
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent::ivDumpEnabled:false
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent::ivResourceBundleName:com.ibm.ws.websvcs.resources.websvcsMessages
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent::ivLogger:null
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent::ivDiagnosticProviderID:null
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent::anyTracingEnabled:false
 END:com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent@60086008

com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet::agent BEGIN:org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ListingAgent@7e527e52
 org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractAgent::DEFAULT_INDEX_JSP:index.jsp
 org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractAgent::METHOD_PREFIX:process
 org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractAgent::log BEGIN:org.apache.axis2.util.OnDemandLogger@7e4c7e4c
  org.apache.axis2.util.OnDemandLogger::c:class org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractAgent
  org.apache.axis2.util.OnDemandLogger::_log:null
  END:org.apache.axis2.util.OnDemandLogger@7e4c7e4c

 org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractAgent::operationCache BEGIN:java.util.HashMap@8880888
  {
  key:index
   value:java.lang.reflect.Method@13731373 depth limit reached
  key:listfaultyservices
   value:java.lang.reflect.Method@13681368 depth limit reached
  key:explicitschemaandwsdl
   value:java.lang.reflect.Method@13891389 depth limit reached
  key:listservice
   value:java.lang.reflect.Method@13aa13aa depth limit reached
  key:unknown
   value:java.lang.reflect.Method@171f171f depth limit reached
  key:listservices
   value:java.lang.reflect.Method@13b513b5 depth limit reached
  }
  END:java.util.HashMap@8880888

 org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractAgent::configContext:org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContext@4ed44ed4
 org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ListingAgent::log BEGIN:org.apache.axis2.util.OnDemandLogger@7e4f7e4f
  org.apache.axis2.util.OnDemandLogger::c:class org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ListingAgent
  org.apache.axis2.util.OnDemandLogger::_log:null
  END:org.apache.axis2.util.OnDemandLogger@7e4f7e4f

 org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ListingAgent::LIST_MULTIPLE_SERVICE_JSP_NAME:listServices.jsp
 org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ListingAgent::LIST_SINGLE_SERVICE_JSP_NAME:listSingleService.jsp
 org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ListingAgent::LIST_FAULTY_SERVICES_JSP_NAME:listFaultyService.jsp
 org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ListingAgent::RUNNING_PORT:RUNNING_PORT
 END:org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ListingAgent@7e527e52

com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet::closeReader:true
com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet::contentType:text/xml; charset=utf-8
com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet::endptMgrMBean:com.ibm.ws.webservices.management.EndpointManagerMBeanImpl@79557955
com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet::bypassEndpointListenerMBean:false
END:com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet@402c402c
```

Answer (score 1):

I too encountered same error while deploying my webservice application in WebSphere V7. It seems to be an bug with WAS server. Post installing an IBM fix pack [7.0.0-WS-WAS-WinX32-FP0000035](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24038310), i was able to get past the error.
Note: please make sure that you are installing "Update Installer 7.0 for WebSphere Software" before installation of fix pack. Updated Installer is available in the same link above.